# Is there a way to block all requests made by chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Almost all useful extensions require permission to access and modify all data on a page.
We can't be sure that a chrome extension is malicious in the sense if it's leaking my data or not.

I realise that many extensions which I use for example the great suspender, even though it needs access to all site data, it doesn't need to communicate with outside world.

Is there a way to block specific chrome extensions from making any network requests at all. ( can we block all outgoing/incoming traffic to a chrome extension. )

I can't keep monitoring a extension 24/7 to see when is it leaking data, For all you know it could be leaking once a month.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to block just the network communication of an extension without blocking its site access (aka "host permissions") entirely. That's because a malicious extension can open a tab with its controlling site (or a hidden iframe in the background script) and insert js code as a standard DOM script which the browser will attribute to the page itself so it'll be able to communicate with the site's domain to upload the exfiltrated data.

So, what you can do practically is to protect the most sensitive sites you use from all extensions by adding a local [`ExtensionSettings` policy](https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=ExtensionSettings) with `runtime_blocked_hosts` that contains that site(s). This will prevent all extensions from accessing the entire site either via content scripts or network requests.  Example: `{"*": {"runtime_blocked_hosts": ["*://lastpass.com"]}}`. And if you have an extension you trust then you can relax this rule for that extension by using `runtime_allowed_hosts`. See the policy link above for more examples.

Comment: But the inserted code will have to follow the same-origin policy right. If I can just have extensions not be able to talk to anyone else except the site domain itself then it's also fine.

Comment: Uhm, the point is that the extension will simply open an iframe to the malicious site to which it'll send the data.